# error: ‘defaultfloat’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++11, debian

`std::defaultfloat` doesn't seem to be defined in GCC, despite being [in the standard](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/defaultfloat/) (I think it's §27.5.6.4). I've isolated it to this simple program:

```
// test.cpp
#include <iostream>                                                             

int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
    std::cout << std::defaultfloat << 1.3;                                      
    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

This compiles in VC++11. I tried compiling this with g++ 4.7.2 and g++ 4.9.0 using both of these commands:

> g++ test.cpp
>   g++ test.cpp -std=c++11

I also tried [an online compile on GCC 4.8.1 here](http://ideone.com/5hcExu), always with the same result:

```
user@office-debian:~/Documents/test$ g++ test.cpp -std=c++11
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:5:15: error: ‘defaultfloat’ is not a member of ‘std’
  std::cout << std::defaultfloat << 1.3;
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Hm. Strange. Do you have a C++ standard library implementation that supports C++11?

Comment: Well I've just installed GCC 4.9.0 and I had the same problem with the standard GCC 4.7.2 install that shipped with Debian. Is that what you mean?

Comment: well, if it installed without problem, I'd expect it to work. Could you please tell me the version of glibc (I'm assuming that's what ships with GCC)?

Comment: @user3477950 It's a GCC thing, not related to my install I think. See this: http://ideone.com/5hcExu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCC `libstdc++` just doesn't support these C++11 manipulators in any of
the versions you've compiled against. A [patch](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2014-03/msg01505.html) was submitted exactly one month ago

Comment: A year later, using G++ 4.9.2 this manipulator is still not supported. If you wish to use all C++11 features, then I strongly recommend to use Clang.