# Building software written in c++ in a Conda environment

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, conda

I am a bioinformatician and work with large genetic datasets. We work with a particular file format ([.bgen](https://www.well.ox.ac.uk/%7Egav/bgen_format/)) for efficiently storing this data, but there is (to my knowledge) only one piece of software that can manipulating these files: [QCTOOL v2](https://www.well.ox.ac.uk/%7Egav/qctool_v2/).

Our computing cluster has an old version of the software (v1 which cannot handle newer specs of the .bgen format) and the administrators will not install the newer version. The pre-compiled binaries for the software do not have access to the required boost libraries, so they are also not an option. Since I don't have root access, I am limited to installing within a conda environment.

The software comes packaged with most of its dependencies, but attempting to compile the software without conda environment runs into issues with the cluster's c++ compiler. I thought that the compiler was the issue, so I created a conda environment and installed [GCC](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gcc), added the conda gcc binary to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and tried to compile QCTOOL, but hit exactly the same error during compilation.

The error that it runs in to is:

```
../../metro/src/regression/Design.cpp: In member function ‘std::string metro::regression::Design::get_summary() const’:
../../metro/src/regression/Design.cpp:239:41: error: ‘defaultfloat’ is not a member of ‘std’
      out << std::setw( widths[j+1] ) << std::defaultfloat << std::setprecision(3) ;
```

and googling reveals [this 8-year old stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319692/error-defaultfloat-is-not-a-member-of-std). From this, and the numerous compiler warnings about `comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions`, I still think the compiler may be the problem.

As I don't have much experience of c++ and I'm limited to conda environments, I don't know what I should try next. I'm asking here as the software, despite being fairly critical, is not well-supported (though I understand the reasons) and updated/bugfixes are infrequent. Given my limited knowledge of c++, I was hoping to avoid editing the code directly but can do so if that's the best way to fix this.

Any help or advice, no matter how basic, would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note: Out of curiosity, I checked [std::defaultfloat in coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30672a6366d59bf7) which has the quite recent gcc V11.2.0. Your [GCC](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gcc) link refers to the same version. (Unfortunately, I don't know for sure which std C++ library is used by default but I assume it's libstdc++.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thanks for taking a quick look. I don't know if the problem is the wrong C++ library in the conda environment or that I (or conda) haven't set all the environment variables correctly, though when I configure the software installation, it looks like it's pointing toward the correct compiler within the conda env.

Comment: 1st - Sorry. I confused things. It's clang++ where you can choose the std lib. but not g++. 2nd - I just tried all the versions I'm aware of. `std::defaultfloat` works in all of them as expected: [Test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/750d3e95b1da930c). Concerning your issue, I haven't a clue. But in general, if I have something installed in two or more versions I sooner or later will use accidentally the wrong one and stumble into a lot of weird issues. For my luck, I'm aware of this now, and which version is used is the first thing I do in such cases. ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure what happens if you use the right compiler but the wrong std libraries. The libstdc++ defines some macros. FYI: [libstdc++ Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_macros.html) Thus, you could write a `std::cout` at an appropriate place to reflect the used version e.g. in a minimal test app. `#include <iostream> int main() { std::cout << _GLIBCXX_RELEASE << std::endl; }`. Compile and run it and check what your build env. is using.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thanks for this. Within the conda environment, just using g++ to compile didn't work unless I pointed to the actual conda g++ binary. When compiled and run, it prints "11". I'm starting to think that it's something to do with how conda handles (or doesn't handle) environment variables. Which environment variables should I be checking? I should have mentioned that I am trying to compile with "waf", which does seem to identify the correct binaries and is happy that the -std=c++11 flag exists (it checks for this). But clearly when compiling, it isn't seeing the right libstdc++.

Comment: I'm not aware of any general env. var. concerning g++. However, there is something simple(?) you could do (may be): If you run a console in conda (or conda in a console), you could modify `PATH`. Either, remove the dir. where the wrong g++ is located in or just re-order the entries so that your preferred g++ is found first. Concerning config. of g++ - no idea but it should be solvable with google.